# jqxGrid inside jqxSplitter automatically maximizes its pane

Tags: javascript, jqxgrid, jqwidget

A jqxsplitter splits screen horizontally. In one of split panes there is a jqxgrid with width=100% and height=100% so that the grid is resized automatically and with scrollbar.

There is a problem where as soon as I click on the grid pane it maximizes to full height closing the other pane.

```
    window.addEventListener('load', function(e){
  $('#tab').jqxSplitter({height:'100%', width: '100%' ,showSplitBar:true,orientation: 'horizontal',  panels: [{ size: '50%'},{ size: '50%'}] });
    var aliases = {
    datatype: 'array',
    localdata: [{col:'a'},{col:'b'}],
    datafields:[
       {name:'col',value:'col',type: 'string'}
    ]}
  var s = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(aliases);
  var columns = [
     { text: 'Column', dataField: 'col', width: 150, editable:true}
     ]
  $('#grid').jqxGrid({
     selectionmode: 'singlerow',
     width:  '100%',
     height:'100%',
     source: s,
     pageable: false,
     sortable: false,
     editable: true,
     columns: columns,
     autoheight:false})}
,true)
```

htm:

```
<div id='tab'>
        <div style="position:relative;">
          a div...
        </div>
          <div id="grid"></div>
      </div>
```

How can maximizing of grid pane inside a splitter be prevented in jqWidgets?

Comment: I'm finding that adding "position:fixed;"to style of div seems to fix the problem. Other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

The general problem here is that your grid's height is set to 100% and you have some additional content above it which makes the resulting height larger than 100%. A simple solution would be if your grid's height is 90% and your other content above/below the Grid is 10% or something else.

Ex:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title id='Description'>In this sample is demonstrated how to integrate jqxGrid with jqxSplitter</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../scripts/demos.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxcore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxbuttons.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxscrollbar.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxmenu.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxgrid.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxgrid.selection.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxgrid.columnsresize.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxdata.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxsplitter.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxinput.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var data = '[{ "CompanyName": "Alfreds Futterkiste", "ContactName": "Maria Anders", "ContactTitle": "Sales Representative", "Address": "Obere Str. 57", "City": "Berlin", "Country": "Germany" }, { "CompanyName": "Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados", "ContactName": "Ana Trujillo", "ContactTitle": "Owner", "Address": "Avda. de la Constitucin 2222", "City": "Mxico D.F.", "Country": "Mexico" }, { "CompanyName": "Antonio Moreno Taquera", "ContactName": "Antonio Moreno", "ContactTitle": "Owner", "Address": "Mataderos 2312", "City": "Mxico D.F.", "Country": "Mexico" }, { "CompanyName": "Around the Horn", "ContactName": "Thomas Hardy", "ContactTitle": "Sales Representative", "Address": "120 Hanover Sq.", "City": "London", "Country": "UK" }, { "CompanyName": "Berglunds snabbkp", "ContactName": "Christina Berglund", "ContactTitle": "Order Administrator", "Address": "Berguvsvgen 8", "City": "Lule", "Country": "Sweden" }, { "CompanyName": "Blauer See Delikatessen", "ContactName": "Hanna Moos", "ContactTitle": "Sales Representative", "Address": "Forsterstr. 57", "City": "Mannheim", "Country": "Germany" }, { "CompanyName": "Blondesddsl pre et fils", "ContactName": "Frdrique Citeaux", "ContactTitle": "Marketing Manager", "Address": "24, place Klber", "City": "Strasbourg", "Country": "France" }, { "CompanyName": "Blido Comidas preparadas", "ContactName": "Martn Sommer", "ContactTitle": "Owner", "Address": "C\/ Araquil, 67", "City": "Madrid", "Country": "Spain" }, { "CompanyName": "Bon app\'", "ContactName": "Laurence Lebihan", "ContactTitle": "Owner", "Address": "12, rue des Bouchers", "City": "Marseille", "Country": "France" }, { "CompanyName": "Bottom-Dollar Markets", "ContactName": "Elizabeth Lincoln", "ContactTitle": "Accounting Manager", "Address": "23 Tsawassen Blvd.", "City": "Tsawassen", "Country": "Canada" }, { "CompanyName": "B\'s Beverages", "ContactName": "Victoria Ashworth", "ContactTitle": "Sales Representative", "Address": "Fauntleroy Circus", "City": "London", "Country": "UK" }, { "CompanyName": "Cactus Comidas para llevar", "ContactName": "Patricio Simpson", "ContactTitle": "Sales Agent", "Address": "Cerrito 333", "City": "Buenos Aires", "Country": "Argentina" }, { "CompanyName": "Centro comercial Moctezuma", "ContactName": "Francisco Chang", "ContactTitle": "Marketing Manager", "Address": "Sierras de Granada 9993", "City": "Mxico D.F.", "Country": "Mexico" }, { "CompanyName": "Chop-suey Chinese", "ContactName": "Yang Wang", "ContactTitle": "Owner", "Address": "Hauptstr. 29", "City": "Bern", "Country": "Switzerland" }, { "CompanyName": "Comrcio Mineiro", "ContactName": "Pedro Afonso", "ContactTitle": "Sales Associate", "Address": "Av. dos Lusadas, 23", "City": "Sao Paulo", "Country": "Brazil" }, { "CompanyName": "Consolidated Holdings", "ContactName": "Elizabeth Brown", "ContactTitle": "Sales Representative", "Address": "Berkeley Gardens 12 Brewery", "City": "London", "Country": "UK" }, { "CompanyName": "Drachenblut Delikatessen", "ContactName": "Sven Ottlieb", "ContactTitle": "Order Administrator", "Address": "Walserweg 21", "City": "Aachen", "Country": "Germany" }, { "CompanyName": "Du monde entier", "ContactName": "Janine Labrune", "ContactTitle": "Owner", "Address": "67, rue des Cinquante Otages", "City": "Nantes", "Country": "France" }, { "CompanyName": "Eastern Connection", "ContactName": "Ann Devon", "ContactTitle": "Sales Agent", "Address": "35 King George", "City": "London", "Country": "UK" }, { "CompanyName": "Ernst Handel", "ContactName": "Roland Mendel", "ContactTitle": "Sales Manager", "Address": "Kirchgasse 6", "City": "Graz", "Country": "Austria"}]';

            // prepare the data
            var source =
            {
                datatype: "json",
                datafields: [
                    { name: 'CompanyName', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'ContactName', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'ContactTitle', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'Address', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'City', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'Country', type: 'string' }
                ],
                localdata: data,
                updaterow: function (rowid, rowdata, commit) {
                    commit(true);
                }
            };
            var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);

            $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid(
            {
                width: '100%',
                height: '90%',
                source: dataAdapter,

                columnsresize: true,
                columns: [
                    { text: 'Company Name', datafield: 'CompanyName', width: 250 },
                    { text: 'Contact Name', datafield: 'ContactName', width: 150 },
                    { text: 'Contact Title', datafield: 'ContactTitle', width: 180 },
                    { text: 'City', datafield: 'City', width: 120 },
                    { text: 'Country', datafield: 'Country'}
                ]
            });

            $("#CompanyName").jqxInput({height: 23});
            $("#ContactName").jqxInput({ height: 23});
            $("#ContactTitle").jqxInput({ height: 23});
            $("#City").jqxInput({ height: 23});
            $("#Country").jqxInput({ height: 23});
            $("#splitter").jqxSplitter({  width: 680, height: 400, panels: [{ min: 150, size: 330 }, {min: 250}] });
            $('#jqxgrid').on('rowselect', function (event) {
                // event arguments.
                var args = event.args;
                // selected row.
                var row = event.args.row;
                // update inputs.
                $("#CompanyName").val(row.CompanyName);
                $("#ContactName").val(row.ContactName);
                $("#ContactTitle").val(row.ContactTitle);
                $("#City").val(row.City);
                $("#Country").val(row.Country);
            });
            $("#Save").jqxButton({  width: 70, height: 23 });
            $("#Save").click(function () {
                var row = $('#jqxgrid').jqxGrid('getselectedrowindex');
                var rowid = $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('getrowid', row);
                var data = { CompanyName: $("#CompanyName").val(), ContactName: $("#ContactName").val(), ContactTitle: $("#ContactTitle").val(), City: $("#City").val(), Country: $("#Country").val() };
                $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('updaterow', rowid, data);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body class='default'>
    <div id="splitter">
        <div>
            <div style="background: blue; height:10%;"></div>
            <div style="border: none;" id='jqxgrid'>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="ContentPanel">
            <form id="Form">
                <table style="margin-top: 20px; width: 100%;">
                     <tr><td style="text-align:right;">Company Name:</td><td style="text-align:left;"><input type="text" id="CompanyName" /></td></tr>
                     <tr><td style="text-align:right;">Contact Name:</td><td style="text-align:left;"><input type="text" id="ContactName" /></td></tr>
                     <tr><td style="text-align:right;">Contact Title:</td><td style="text-align:left;"><input type="text" id="ContactTitle" /></td></tr>
                     <tr><td style="text-align:right;">City:</td><td style="text-align:left;"><input type="text" id="City" /></td></tr>
                     <tr><td style="text-align:right;">Country:</td><td style="text-align:left;"><input type="text" id="Country" /></td></tr>
                     <tr><td></td><td style="padding-left: 35px; text-align: left;"><input value="Save" type="button" id="Save" /></td></tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the sizes are not fixed. when web page opens some panes are closed, for example the grid pane in question. div sizes are dynamic not sure how presetting them would work.